# Why are there infinitely many x11 subdirectories in /usr/bin/x11?

Tags: xorg, filesystem, directory

Why does the `/usr/bin/x11` folder hold another `x11` folder and when you open that `x11` you get another `x11` and then another and another?

I did it about 6 times and got frustrated so I have no idea how deep this goes but

- What is the purpose (or is it a glitch?)?
- Is this eating disk space more than it should? (I was going to delete one or more but thought I better ask first )

I can see no reason why this should be happening at all.

Answer (score 31):

`/usr/bin/X11/` is a symbolic link (symlink) pointing to `/usr/bin/`. Hence it contains itself and you can follow those `X11` folders all day long but there's still just one on your disk.

This is for compatibility reasons as some programs expect some other program to be in `/usr/bin/X11/` but Ubuntu puts them in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Exactly - its a Link to the same directory that the link itself is in.  It looks like a paradox but it's not.

Answer (score 6):

`/usr/bin/X11` is not a directory but a file, specifically a symbolic link.
Use

```
$ ll /usr/bin/X11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 dec  3 13:01 /usr/bin/X11 -> ./
```

to see that it is a link (`l` as first letter in the answer) and that it points to the containing directory `./`, while keeping on existing as a file inside that directory.

**It's like a window giving a view on the inside of a shop --- you can sneak inside from outside, but you can also see the same window as a part of the whole shop.**

More concisely, you can discover this also with

```
$ realpath /usr/bin/X11
/usr/bin
```

since `realpath` resolves the target of links and gives its absolute path. (In some distribution `realpath` is a core utility that needs to be installed, and it's useful to have.)