# Why are the 'same' executables in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/bin/X11/`? Are they really the same?

Tags: xorg, filesystem, gcc, symbolic-link

With Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am working on a custom install of [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/) that I want to put alongside the supported version that is too old for my purposes.

My computer has version 4.8.4 installed from the Ubuntu repository, and I was looking at `whereis gcc` to see how the gcc files are arranged in the filesystem normally.

I then noticed that the same executables are stored both in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/bin/X11` (using `ll -L` on both folders). The following questions arise:

- In general, what is the purpose of `/usr/bin/X11/` as distinct from `/usr/bin/`? I have looked into the [standard filesystem hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), and `/usr/bin/X11/` is no standard directory;
- In particular, is it correct to assume that the files in `/usr/bin/X11/` are just a copycat of those in `/usr/bin/` as a matter of rule? The new `gcc` has no `<mount point>/bin/X11` folder in its tree. This is useful to know in order to redirect with confidence the existing symlinks in `/usr/bin/X11` to the executables of the new version (no-devil-in-the-details point of caution).

Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /bin/X11` report?

Comment: So no package created that. You should ask your system administrator

Comment: Correction, with apologies. The directories I mentioned earlier are under `/usr` rather than `/`.  The post has been edited accordingly. The answer to `dpkg -S /usr/bin/X11` is `x11-common: /usr/bin/X11`. (In general, I am my system administrator)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/191654/158442 and `/usr/share/doc/x11-common/NEWS.Debian.vz`

Comment: Once upon a time there was no GUI. And when the X Window System appeared, it came with wondrous graphical programs such as xterm and xclock and so on. And people used to put those graphical programs in a special directory, which in time became `/usr/bin/X11`. But nowadays all binaries live in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`; while `/usr/bin/X11` serves no purpose any longer, it is still created as a symlink to `/usr/bin` in order to keep compatibility with old sysadmins and old scripts, which are used to xterm being `/usr/bin/X11/xterm`.

Comment: `ll /usr/bin/X11`gives `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 dec  3 13:01 /usr/bin/X11 -> ./` --- this confirms the understanding that `/usr/bin/X11` points to itself but not that it points to `/usr/bin`, the parent directory `..` --- how does this match with the statements that `/usr/bin/X11` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`? @AlexP @muru

Comment: @XavierStuvw: `/usr/bin/X11` is a file in `/usr/bin`. It is a symlink pointing to the current directory, `.`; this makes `/usr/bin/X11` a synonym for `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @AlexP Clear! `/usr/bin/X11` shoudl not be mistaken as a directory in the first place. Thx

Comment: @AlexP Please convert your 'once upon a time' story and additions into an answer, and I'll be glad to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once upon a time there was no GUI. And when the [X Window System appeared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), it came with wondrous graphical programs such as [`xterm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) and `xclock` and so on, and with utilities such as [`xrdb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrdb) and `xmodmap`. And people used to put those graphical programs in a special directory, which in time became `/usr/bin/X11`. (X**11** because the the final version of the [X Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) is 11, specifically X version 11 release 6 point 4, X11R6.4; before X11 there were and X9 and an X10.)

But nowadays all executables live in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`; while `/usr/bin/X11` serves no purpose any longer, it is still created as a *[symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)* to `/usr/bin` in order to keep compatibility with old sysadmins and old scripts, which are used to `xterm` being `/usr/bin/X11/xterm`.

So the answer is that it is not the executables which are the same in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/bin/X11`: it is `/usr/bin/X11` itself which is the same as `/usr/bin`.

If you look you will notice that `/usr/bin/X11` is a symlink to `.`. This is called a *relative* symlink: `/usr/bin/X11` being a file in `/usr/bin` and a symlink pointing to the current directory, `.`, this makes `/usr/bin/X11` a synonym for `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to discover what the path and file actually point to, do

```
$ realpath /usr/bin/X11
/usr/bin
```

Fun variant:

```
$ myDir=/usr/bin/X11
$ echo $(realpath -s $myDir) is in fact $(realpath $myDir)
/usr/bin/X11 is in fact /usr/bin
```

This is the on-line [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/realpath.1) of `realpath`.

Thanks @AlexP and @muru for putting me on the right track