# How can I find where the vim executable is located when my PATH is broken?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, environment-variables, vim

Looks like I crashed my system after editing `/etc/environment` and `.bashrc` files.

My desktop doesn't start and I need to correct these files back. But since my system doesn't find any commands I need to use the whole path.

Where I can find the vim executable so I can run it with its full path?

Comment: @pa4080 none of those commands will work with a problematic `PATH`, except maybe the one answer about aliases, and that won't help here.

Comment: Hi, @Olorin, I'm agree and retracted my suggestion. Actually `PATH= which vim` produces: *`-bash: which: No such file or directory`*. I already saw [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/986424/566421) and I think it should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your `PATH` environment variable was corrupted.

You can find `vim` in `/usr/bin/vim`

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

In `/usr/bin` you should find also `vi` and `gedit`

`nano` can be found in `/bin`

```
$ which nano
/bin/nano
```

`sudo` can be found in `/usr/bin`

```
$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
```

Notes:

As mentioned by @SorenA and @PatrickMevzek search for a location of a file can also be done using `whereis`

As mentioned by @Terrance - `whereis vim` finds all names with like vim in the name, Note that most of the results aren't the `vim` executable.

> `man which` - locate a command - It does this by searching the PATH
>   for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.
>
> `man whereis` - whereis  then  attempts  to  locate  the desired 
>   program in the standard Linux places, and in the places speci‐fied by
>   $PATH and $MANPATH.

Comment: or `whereis` that checks standard directories (`which` checks directories in user's `$PATH` so depending on how it is set up some locations may be missed)

Comment: Don't update your answer.  `whereis` finds all names with like `vim` in the name.  I see one that says `/etc/vim` and if you try to run it it says that it is a directory.  Whereis locates where which finds the executable that is in the path.

Comment: If `which` doesn't work, because PATH variable has been corrupted, `whereis` is a usefull alternative. Start looking in /bin and /usr/bin - you find most things there, if you still hasn't found your exec, use whereis.

Comment: found vim, but can't find sudo , since I need permitions. Where is sudo?

Comment: `which which` ...

Comment: Neither `whereis` nor `which` would be runnable without knowing *their* path. Both are in `/usr/bin`, where `vim` resides, so if `vim` can't be found, then these can't be either.

Answer (score 4):

Since your PATH is corrupted the useful executables are in the `/usr/bin` and `/bin` folders. From a terminal type in

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

then you should be able to run `sudo vim` without the need to type in the paths in front of the names.

The following commands will restore the `/etc/environment` file and the `~/.bashrc` file.

This command will put the path statement back in `/etc/environment`:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "PATH=\"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games\"" > /etc/environment'
```

Then you can source the file so the PATH statement sets:

```
. /etc/environment
```

Then get a default `.bashrc` file and put it back in your home folder:

```
sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/$USER/.bashrc
sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the best possible solution - reset to a sane default `PATH` for your current shell.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure bash, you could run a search for things named `vim`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar  
$ time echo /**/vim
/etc/alternatives/vim /etc/vim /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/X11/vim /usr/share/cmake-3.5/editors/vim /usr/share/vim /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim /var/lib/vim

real    0m4.145s
user    0m0.740s
```

You could then loop over the results to see which are executable:

```
$ time for v in /**/vim; do [[ -x $v && -f $v ]] && echo "$v"; done
/etc/alternatives/vim
/usr/bin/vim
/usr/bin/X11/vim
```

Notes:

- `/etc/alternatives/vim` is [the alternative system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) in play
- `/usr/bin/X11/vim` appears because `/usr/bin/X11` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`, so everything in the latter appears in the former. [Why are there infinitely many x11 subdirectories in /usr/bin/x11?](https://askubuntu.com/q/191654/760903)

---

With various breakages in Ubuntu, there's a single command that can help with a lot of things: `/bin/busybox`. Remembering just this one gets you access to a lot more:

```
$ /bin/busybox 
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) multi-call binary.
BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 1998-2012.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed
copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
   or: busybox --list[-full]
   or: busybox --install [-s] [DIR]
   or: function [arguments]...

    BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
    utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
    link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
    will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
    [, [[, acpid, adjtimex, ar, arp, arping, ash, awk, basename, blockdev,
    brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2, cal, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chpasswd,
    chroot, chvt, clear, cmp, cp, cpio, crond, crontab, cttyhack, cut,
    date, dc, dd, deallocvt, depmod, devmem, df, diff, dirname, dmesg,
    dnsdomainname, dos2unix, dpkg, dpkg-deb, du, dumpkmap, dumpleases,
    echo, ed, egrep, env, expand, expr, false, fdisk, fgrep, find, fold,
    free, freeramdisk, fstrim, ftpget, ftpput, getopt, getty, grep, groups,
    gunzip, gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostid, hostname, httpd, hwclock,
    id, ifconfig, ifdown, ifup, init, insmod, ionice, ip, ipcalc, kill,
    killall, klogd, last, less, ln, loadfont, loadkmap, logger, login,
    logname, logread, losetup, ls, lsmod, lzcat, lzma, lzop, lzopcat,
    md5sum, mdev, microcom, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mkswap, mktemp, modinfo,
    modprobe, more, mount, mt, mv, nameif, nc, netstat, nslookup, od,
    openvt, passwd, patch, pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, poweroff,
    printf, ps, pwd, rdate, readlink, realpath, reboot, renice, reset, rev,
    rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, rpm, rpm2cpio, run-parts, sed, seq,
    setkeycodes, setsid, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha512sum, sleep, sort,
    start-stop-daemon, stat, static-sh, strings, stty, su, sulogin,
    swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd, tac, tail, tar,
    taskset, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, tftp, time, timeout, top, touch,
    tr, traceroute, traceroute6, true, tty, tunctl, udhcpc, udhcpd, umount,
    uname, uncompress, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos, unlzma, unlzop, unxz,
    unzip, uptime, usleep, uudecode, uuencode, vconfig, vi, watch,
    watchdog, wc, wget, which, who, whoami, xargs, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat
```

Yep, that includes `vi`.